# How to pass a value to fxml scene

Tags: user-interface, methods, javafx, fxml

I'm making this javaFX application, but in a given moment i wanna get the text exibited in the scene from a method in anothe class, how can i pass this value to my text box in the FXML doccument?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.72" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.crapgames.calourosimulator.views.pcna.intro.Introduction">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="imgClick" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="800.0" onMouseClicked="#nextScene" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../assets/pnca-monitor-text.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Text fx:id="text1" fill="#f5eded" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="452.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="where i want my string variable" wrappingWidth="787.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Comic Sans MS" size="25.0" />
         </font></Text>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the controller class to accept the text value. You can leverage the `textProperty` of the `Text` if you want:

```
public class Introduction {

    @FXML
    private Text text1 ;

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text1.textProperty();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    // existing code ...

}
```

Now you can do:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml/file.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
Introduction controller = loader.getController();
controller.setText("Hello World!");

Scene scene = new Scene(root);

// etc...
```